# Simultaneous updates across two display contexts in openGL

Tags: c#, opengl

I have a C# .NET application with which I've created a custom image display control. Each image display represents its own display context and draws the image using glDrawPixels (Yes I know it would be better to use textures, I plan to in the futures but this app is already too far along and my time is limited).

I am now trying to have both images pan simultaneously. That is, when one image is moved down ten pixels, the second image moves down ten pixels. Like so:

```
imageOne.YPan -= 10;
imageTwo.YPan -= 10;
imageOne.Invalidate(); //This forces a redraw.
imageTwo.Invalidate(); //This forces a redraw.
```

Alright so here is the problem I am having. Only one of the images displays is redrawing. If I place a pause in between the two Invalidate calls and make the pause duration at least 110 milliseconds both will redraw, but not simultaneously. So it looks as if the second image is always trying to catch up to the first. Plus, a 110 millisecond pause slows down the motion too much.

I have tried placing the updating and invalidating of each image in its own thread but this did not help.

At the beginning of drawing I make the appropriate context is current, and at the end I am calling swapbuffers(). I tried adding a glFinish to the end of the draw function, but there was no change.

Could it be that its the graphics card that is the problem? I am stuck using an integrated gpu that only has openGL 1.4.

Hopefully, I have provided enough detail that the answer to my problem can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult telling what's wrong with what you do since you give so little detail. Here are some pointers which may help.
- before doing something in a context, make sure you make it the current one. If you want to pan two contexts, make the first one current, pan it and then make the second one current and pan it. These is no real reason why this should not work.
- If it looks like there is a timing problem, adding `glFinish()` at strategic places may help weed the problem out
- As should always be done, on occasions call `glError()` and see that everything went well.
- I'm not sure how this is done in the framework you're talking about but you should make sure that both contexts get a `swapBuffers()` call for every frame.

Answer (score 0):

`Invalidate` doesn't force an immediate redraw.  It marks the window invalid, and when the message queue runs out of other messages, a paint message will be created and processed.  But that won't happen until you finish processing the current message and return to the main message loop, and it may be delayed even more than that.

Generally OpenGL animation is an exception to the rule of doing all drawing inside `Control.OnPaint` (or in a handler for the `Control.Paint` event).